# A question about a ring in the form of a direct product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Atiyah-Macdonald's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" **(Pg. 20)** says the following:

> Suppose that the ring $A$ is a direct product $\Pi_{i=1}^n A_i$. Then the set of all elements of $A$ of the form $$(0,0,\dots,0,a_i,0,\dots0,0)$$ with $a\in A_i$ is an ideal $a_i$ of $A$. The ring $A$ is the direct sum of the ideals $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$

1. Are $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ all rings?
2. The ideal $a_1$ of $A$ is of the form $(a_1,0,0,\dots,0)$. Similarly, $a_2$ is of the form $(0,a_2,0,0,\dots,0)$. What is $a_1\oplus a_2$? Shouldn't it be of the form $(a_1,0,\dots,0,0,a_2,\dots,0)$, which is a $2n$-tuple?
3. How is the product of two $n$-tuples defined? Wouldn't it need to be defined for $A$ to be a ring? Is it component-wise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, all the $A_i$ are rings.

2) Here the term "direct sum" means internal direct sum, which basically just means "sum", but with the additional property that the ideals intersect trivially.

3) Yes, the product is component-wise (just like the sum).

Comment: How would you in general distinguish between the symbols for internal direct sum and external direct sum? I have seen the same symbol used for both.

Comment: There is not really any way to distinguish them other than context. And even then, they are not quite different anyway, since they give the same up to isomorphism. I generally think of it this way: The external direct sum of "things" is a construction which gives a "thing" which contains two sub-"things" and such that this new "thing" is the internal direct sum of those two sub-"things" (replace "thing" by whatever type of object you want to take direct sums of).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. and 3.: Addition and multiplication is defined component-wise. So $a_1 \oplus a_2 = (a_1, a_2, 0, ..., 0)$.

Comment: But when you take $A\oplus B$, isn't it generally of the form $(a,b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$? Say $A=M\oplus N$ and $B=P\oplus Q$. Then $A\oplus B=(m,n,p,q)$, isn't this accurate?

Comment: Either you use the characterization Tobias Kildetoft suggested in his answer, or you take your definition and you get that $a_1 \oplus a_2$ is isomorphic as an A-module to $(a_1, a_2, 0, ...0)$ by sending $((a_1, 0 ,..., 0), (0, a_2, ..., 0))$ to $(a_1, a_2, 0, ..., 0)$.